# how to use other module data source to new module in magento 2

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, resource-model, di

> Hi **I want to use the data source of module 1 to module 2 in Magento 2**
>
> how I can do this ??

*vendor/module2/etc/module.xml*

```
<sequence>
<module name=vendor_module1/>
</sequence>
```

how I declare in

di.xml

Comment: please explain brifly

Comment: i have two modules

Comment: v_m1   had    data source declared

v_m2 with no data source

Comment: i want to get the data source of v_m1 to 
my v_m2  module

Comment: what do you mean by data source??

Comment: for backend admin panel grid